# XCode 4, errors and warnings

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

How do I get XCode to always display errors and warnings. Anytime I build my iPhone app, I can see my errors and warnings on the left menu. But when I click a particular class, I just see little marks on the left side:

[image]

I'd like to be able to see the actual warning or error (which happens only if I click the exclamation points in that image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on that icon you will see the warning/error:

http://d.pr/3DEM+

Or you can also choose

http://d.pr/YNMI+

And if you actually build your app, details will show up in the Log navigator.

http://d.pr/nHyJ+

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the Issue Navigator Tab (4th tab) on the Left Navigator Pane it will show you the warnings and errors in your Project as you develop or when you build the application.

[image: errors]

Comment: that looks like xcode 4, in xcode 3 it was in a different window, called build status or something...

Comment: yes, I already know that. but I want the errors to show in the actual file I am viewing...

Comment: I don't think you can configure that. The only setting Xcode has for Errors is in the General Tab of the Settings Pane where you can Enable Live Issues in Editors and the Issue Navigator